# How do I set the X and Y axis of a EmbeddedChartBuilder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this app script function to create a new chart:

```js
function newChart(range, sheet) {
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
    .addRange(range)
    .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
    .setOption("title", "Model run 1")
    .setOption("pointSize", 2)
    .setOption("lineWidth", 1)
    .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

How would I change the x and y axis, I want to be able to specify what column of my range should be series and what the x axis. How would I do this?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `How would I change the x and y axis, I want to be able to specify what column of my range should be series and what the x axis.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike I have a chart and I column B of my range to be the x axis and column A to be the y axis, does that make sence?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I have a chart and I column B of my range to be the x axis and column A to be the y axis, does that make sence?`, in your current situation, the x and y axes are the columns "A" and "B", respectively, and you want to change the columns "A" and "B" to "B" and "A" in the same sheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: By guessing your goal, I proposed 3 sample scripts as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If those were not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample situation and scripts?

The sample Spreadsheet is as follows.

[image]

In the following sample scripts, this Spreadsheet is used as a sample.

### Create new chart.

#### Sample 1

```js
function sample1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var colA = sheet.getRange("A1:A6");
  var colB = sheet.getRange("B1:B6");

  var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
    .addRange(colA)
    .addRange(colB)
    .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true) // This might not be required to be used.
    .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
    .setOption("title", "Sample 1")
    .setOption("pointSize", 2)
    .setOption("lineWidth", 1)
    .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

In this script, the following chart is created.

[image]

#### Sample 2

```js
function sample2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var colA = sheet.getRange("A1:A6");
  var colB = sheet.getRange("B1:B6");

  var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
    .addRange(colB)
    .addRange(colA)
    .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true) // This might not be required to be used.
    .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
    .setOption("title", "Sample 2")
    .setOption("pointSize", 2)
    .setOption("lineWidth", 1)
    .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

In this script, the following chart is created.

[image]

### Update chart.

#### Sample 3

```js
function sample3() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  var ranges = chart.getRanges();
  var c = chart.modify();
  ranges.forEach(r => c.removeRange(r));
  ranges.reverse().forEach(r => c.addRange(r));
  sheet.updateChart(c.build());
}
```

- When this script is run, the existing chart is updated. The ranges of the x and y axes are replaced to y and x, respectively.

### Note:

- **In these sample scripts, in order to explain the flow of the script, it supposes that there are only 2 columns for the chart. Please be careful about this.**

### References:

- [insertChart(chart)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertchartchart)
- [updateChart(chart)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#updatechartchart)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: precisly what I needed I did not realize i could add range more then once, tyvm.

Comment: @tovernaar123 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.